# SSIS - OleDB connection not updating data, inserted thru SQLBulkCopy with SQL Connection

Tags: ssis, sqlconnection, sqlbulkcopy, oledbconnection

I have created Ole DB connection to execute different SQL task across SSIS package. Its working fine too.

In one of task where i need to do insert data into table, used SQLBulkCopy as i have dynamic tables and columns based on getting files from different sources.

SQLBulkCopy only works with SqlConnection, so i opened SqlConnection, executed SqlBulkCopy. This is also working fine.

After done with SqlBulkCopy, i have created Sql Task which updates metadata of inserted rows, for e.g. Count, Min & Max date and so on in different table.
This table is not getting updated and if i execute stored procedure from Sql Management Studio, it works as expected.

So my assumption is that, Ole DB connection is not able to get the latest data Data inserted thru SQL Connection.

I may be wrong, but not sure why i can see sql execution task successful but still table is not updated.

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

Instead of passing data type as long (int in SQL), i was passing it as Varchar.

I was looking from last few hours and as soon as i post question here, it strikes me to check the data type.

Hope it will help somebody.